# Sort first column while merging second column

Tags: sorting, unix, uniq

I am looking for a solution of the following problem. I have a text file with in the first column geneIDs and in the second single GOterms. Because each gene has multiple annotated GOterms, identical geneIDs do occur multiple times (with different GOterms in the second column. I only want to have unique geneIDs with GOterms merged:
I have:

```
TRINITY_DN10151_c0_g1   GO:0004175
TRINITY_DN10151_c0_g1   GO:0004252
TRINITY_DN10151_c0_g1   GO:0006508
TRINITY_DN10151_c0_g1   GO:0008233
TRINITY_DN102626_c42_g1 GO:0005198
TRINITY_DN102626_c42_g1 GO:0042302
TRINITY_DN102626_c58_g1 GO:0004175
```

I want:

```
TRINITY_DN10151_c0_g1 GO:0004175-GO:0004252-GO:0006508-GO:0008233
TRINITY_DN102626_c42_g1 GO:0005198-GO:0042302
```

etc..

Further it is important (and I have truly no idea how to solve this) that each GO term combination occurs once. So if two genes have the same GO term combination (A, B and C) in column 2 they should both have A-B-C. And not also A-C-B..

I have tried to use sort and uniq, but in the end I was only deleting rows.

Can someone help me with a unix solution?

Comment: I noticed that the format of my text was changed. So in my file on each row I now have a single gene ID with a single GO term: 
    TRINITY_DN10151_c0_g1 GO:0004175
But I want to have all GOterms of similar gene ID's merged. With only a single GOterm combination order for similar GOterm combinations.

Comment: What happened to the `c58`? Are you dropping input rows that don't combine with any other input rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a rather cryptic `sed` command. (Every `sed` command is trivial or cryptic.)

```
sort filename | sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/^\([^ ]* \) *\(.*\)\n\1 */\1\2-/;ta' -e 'P;D'
```

Loosely translated, this says *"Append the next line to this one and replace the newline and second gene name with a hyphen, as long as the two gene names are the same".*

And the `sort` is to keep the GOterm order consistent across genes.

Comment: This seems not to work yet.. I get exactly the same output as I would just use "sort Filename". How can I combine the GO-terms into subgroups (like above)?

Comment: @T_R: My best guess is that it's a whitespace problem. I assumed that those were *spaces* in your input file; if they're *tabs,* or some combination of the two, the command may not work. Try `sed 'N;s/\n[^ ]* /-/'` and report the result (here, in a comment).